# Symfony2 + psliwa PHPPdf

Tags: php, symfony

I have installed pdliwa PHPPdf in my Symfony2, I was testing the examples in the route \vendor\psliwa\php-pdf\examples and all worked fine except one.

The one that isnt working is barcode.xml. When I try to test it this error msg appear:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Zend\Barcode\Object\Code128' not found in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\vendor\psliwa\php-pdf\lib\PHPPdf\Core\Node\Barcode.php line 175
```

I have zendframework in my vendor folder.

Anyone knows whats the problem?

Comment: The error looks fairly clear, the class Code128 is not found. Check the namespaceing within that class?

Comment: i tried putting the Barcode folder everywhere and i didnt find the correct place for it

Comment: line 173:            $barcodeClass = sprintf('Zend\Barcode\Object\%s', ucfirst($this->getAttribute('type'))); and the namespace is 'namespace PHPPdf\Core\Node;' from https://github.com/psliwa/PHPPdf/blob/master/lib/PHPPdf/Core/Node/Barcode.php

Comment: so to test where its looking print_r($barcodeClass) , then check the namespaceing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update  your composer.json file, adding zend-barcode and zend-validator (which is required by zend-barcode). Then it works.